# Can we use Google analytics to get first time visitors vs repeat visitors sub-domain wise?

Tags: google-analytics-api

We need to get first time visitors vs repeat visitors sub-domain wise on a monthly basis using Google Analytics API, can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to post an answer here, the best I can right now, any suggestions on this way, do let me know

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_usertype

ga:users
UI Name: Users

The total number of users for the requested time period. (We can specify start end dates of months and call this api for each month)

ga:newUsers
UI Name: New Users

The number of users whose session was marked as a first-time session. (We can specify start end dates of months and call this api for each month)

or use the following

ga:30dayUsers
ga:percentNewSessions